# Nested $broadcast within $on

Tags: angularjs

Is possible to create a new `$broadcast` within `$on` ?

Like this

```
$rootScope.$on('line:lineStatus', function(e) {

  $rootScope.$broadcast('hola:line');

});
```

if so, is there any adversity/something wrong with it ?

**The reason why I am asking this:**

with JS there is bunch of stuff you can do, you can achieve the same thing in 50 different ways, but not all those ways are the proper way. So that's why I am asking this.

Comment: could you add more code please.?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, there's nothing wrong with it, except no one being able to think of a good reason to do it so far (updating from comments).

Comment: Except the fact it will lead to spaghetti and hard-to-reason-about code, that is

Comment: That's true - I am trying to think of a valid reason to do it. The initial thought is if statements, but there isn't any real reason to do that inside the $on rather than the original broadcast.

Comment: @DanPantry with JS there is bunch of stuff you can do, you can achieve the same in 50 different ways, but not all those ways are the proper one. So that's why I am asking this.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer that may be, but cascading events are an anti pattern. The entire React library exists to circumvent this scenario.